# Print an array like an object in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I konw that an array is an object in Java. I want to print one array like other objects but this won't work:

```
public static Object[] join(Object[] obj1,Object[] obj2)
{
    Object[] sum=new Object[obj1.length+obj2.length];
    int i=0;
    for(;i<obj1.length;i++)
    {
        sum[i]=obj1[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<obj2.length;j++,i++)        {
        sum[i]=obj2[j];
       // i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] array={1,2,3,4,5};
    Object[] obj1={"Nguyen Viet Q",28,"Doan Thi Ha",array};
    Object[] obj2={"Nguyen Viet Q1",28,"Doan Thi Ha1"};
    join(obj1,obj2);
    for(Object o: join(obj1,obj2))
    {
        System.out.print(o.toString()+" ");// i want to print array object
    }        
}
```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by inserting reference variable `array` in line:`Object[] obj1={"Nguyen Viet Quan",28,"Doan Thi Ha",array};`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your `join` method only needs one loop to copy `obj2` as well as `obj1`. You could find the maximum length for your loop test. And then copy on each *valid* index. That might look something like

```
public static Object[] join(Object[] obj1, Object[] obj2) {
    Object[] sum = new Object[obj1.length + obj2.length];
    int len = Math.max(obj1.length, obj2.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i < obj1.length) {
            sum[i] = obj1[i];
        }
        if (i < obj2.length) {
            sum[i + obj1.length] = obj2[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then you need to save a reference to your joined `obj` (or `print` it directly). And because it contains a nested array, you might choose [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Object[] obj1 = { "Nguyen Viet Quan", 28, "Doan Thi Ha", array };
    Object[] obj2 = { "Nguyen Viet Quan1", 28, "Doan Thi Ha1" };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(join(obj1, obj2)));
}
```

which outputs (formatted for this post)

```
[Nguyen Viet Quan, 28, Doan Thi Ha, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    Nguyen Viet Quan1, 28, Doan Thi Ha1]
```

Comment: The code for join proposed by OP also works and the only change needed is to print multi-dim array using `deepToString`.